# Copy an existing XML element into the same document

Tags: c#, xml

I am building up an XML document using c#. I use AppendChild to add an element called say "test" to a parent element in the document.

I then build up more of the xmlDocument but further down the same document I wish to append the same element "test" to a different node.

I have tried using AppendChild but it added it to the new node and removed it from the existing one. Which I guess is expected. I was just wondering is there anything available that I can use to copy the existing element and add it to a new node without removing it from the existing position?

To perhaps help explain the following code results in the test element only appearing in parentElement2.

```
parentElement1.AppendChild(test)
...
parentElement2.AppendChild(test)
```

Is there anyway I can insert test into both parent elements?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible with the [`CloneNode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.clonenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It lets you create a (possibly deep) copy of a node, which you can then insert wherever you like in your document.